# How to create subsite with custom layout in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

SubSite creats this way in sharepoint 2013
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOHJT.png)

But i want create subsite in step by step. similar to 2nd image. 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCAae.png)

if anyone have a solution or Reference or a word search in google  how to create subsite in that way then pls share with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve above by following below:

1. Create a list with the fields mentioned in the snapshot
2. Modify the form with Nintex, InfoPath or Client side rendering depending upon availability & comfort in mentioned options
3. For sub-site creation, you can either JS CSOM, web-services etc.
4. Follow [this](http://www.ktskumar.com/2009/04/webservice-subsites/) link for info on how to create sub-site using web-services
5. Follow [this](http://spdeveloper.co.in/sharepoint2013/JS-CSOM-code-to-create-a-subsite-using-a-custom-Site-Template.aspx) link for info on how to create sub-site using JS CSOM
6. One done, you can ask user to request site using newform.aspx of the list

**Pls. note that I've not tested the code**